# Solving a Difference Equation.

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

Consider the following difference equation:

$y(n+2) -4y(n) = 2^{n+3} - 1, \quad n \geq 0$.

Here is my try: First we must find the solution of the homogenous difference equation, we do this by solving the characteristic equation: $r^2 - 4 = 0 \implies r_1 = 2, r_2 = -2.$

Thus our solution to the homogenous equation is $y_H(n) = A2^n + B(-2)^n$, which subsequently give the general solution $y(n) = A2^n + B(-2)^n + u^*$, where $u^*$ is a particular solution of the given difference function. To find a particular solution we consider the general form $u^* = 2^{n+3} + C$. Then we find

$2^{n+5} + C - 4 \cdot (2^{n+3} + C) = 2^{n+3} - 1 \implies  -3 \cdot 2^{n+3} + 4 -3C = 2^{n+3} - 1 \implies C = \frac{4 \cdot 2^{n+3} - 5}{ -3}$

This thus eventually gives us the following general solution: $y(n) = A2^n + B(-2)^n + 2^{n+3} + \frac{4 \cdot 2^{n+3} - 5}{ -3}$

But this seems rather odd to me, the solution's manual uses the annihilator method but I do not understand that. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Z-transform?

Comment: No I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Your implication is wrong: $2^{n+5}-42^{n+3} = 2^{n+5}-2^{n+5}=0$.

Comment: The particular solution you claim can actually be written $a2^n + b$. Since the $A2^n$'s are homogeneous solutions, this would imply the existence of a constant solution, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: So if I consider the particular solution to be $a2^n +b$ I will eventually get a correct particular solution?

Comment: No, this is the point of my comment. This would imply that the constant sequence $b$ is also a particular solution (which is not the case).

Comment: What would you have used as the 'guess' of the particular solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150930/discussion-between-reded-and-kemit4).

Comment: Have you tried $n2^n$?

Answer (score 3):

Since the right-hand side has a term that is proportional to a homogenous solution, we attempt a particular solution of the form $A+Bn2^n$.  Proceeding, we find that the particular solution $y_p$ is given by

$$y_p(n)=1/3+n2^n$$

Comment: The solution set is affine (a particular solution plus the vectorial space of homogeneous ones). Indeed, the difference of two solutions must be homogeneous. It is therefore impossible to have both '+' and '-' $1/3$ correct.

Answer (score 1):

[Repost from the chat] It suffices to try $an2^n + b$.
Two approaches to get that.

First, the annihilator method, which considers the [left-shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) $\tau\colon(u_n)\mapsto (u_{n+1})$. The picture solution you sent factorizes the left-hand term using $\tau$, as well as the equation satisfied by the right-hand term. Those two factorizations have (in total) two non-common roots: $-2$ and $1$, as well as the common root $2$. Therefore, it searches for solutions as linear combinations of $(-2^n)$, $1^n$, and $(an+b)2^n$.
As you have pointed out, we already know $2^n$ and $(-2)^n$ to be homogeneous solutions (since the left-hand term factorizes with roots $2$ and $-2$). We can thus focus on an expression of the form $an2^n + c1^n$.

A second approach consists in using an analog of the [Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) as suggested by @Mark Viola. An analog of the Z-transform associates to a sequence $(u_n){n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ the power series $\sum u_n x^n$.
The sequence equation corresponds to $(\frac 1 {x^2} - 4) f(x) = \frac 8 {1-2x} - \frac 1 {1-x}$ for the transform $f$. By re-arranging we get $f$ as a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) (the quotient of two polynomials). We can then consider its [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) (i.e with irreducible polynomials) by classical methods, *or with a mathematical software, what can make this method faster than the above*. Each fraction can easily be expressed as a power series, which provides a particular solution by looking at the power series coefficients of this function (inverse transform).

Comment: Thank you very much! But how do I find the roots of RHS ($2^{n+3} -1$), which are 2 and 1 as you mentioned?

Comment: Maybe to clarify myself: from the RHS ($2^{n+3} -1$), how do I find the order of the RHS and with that a,b and/or c which solve $(\tau +a)(\tau +b)(\tau + c) = 0$. Where a,b and c are dependent of the order of the homogenous difference equation.

Comment: @Kemit4 the operator $(\tau−a\mathrm{id})(\tau−b\mathrm{id})$
 is linear as a composition of linear operators. It thus makes sense to separate the constant part and the $2^{n+3}$. Furthemore, the eigenvectors of $\tau$ for some $\lambda$ are the span of $\lambda^n$. Therefore since $\tau-1\mathrm{id}$ annihilates $(-1)\times 1^n$ and $\tau-2\mathrm{id}$ annihilates $2^{n+3}=8\times2^n$, the (commutative) composition annihilates $2^{n+3}-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try a simpler approach. I believe this is the annihilator method. Basically, starting with

$$
y(n) = 4y(n-2) + 2\cdot2^n - 1, \quad n \geq 0,\ y_0,\ y_1
$$

Since you've already determined that 2^n is a characteristic root, we can assume a solution of the form

$$
y_n=f_n+an2^n+b
$$

The *annihilator* method is then to substitute this into the above recurrence and choose $a,b$ such that we left with only homogeneous recurrence with $f_0=y_0-b$ and $f_1=y_1-2a-b$. Following through,
I find that $a=1$ and $b=1/3$, in agreement with @MarkViola. However, it is important to pay attention to the modified initial conditions on the homogeneous equation

$$
f_n=4f_{n-2}
$$

Comment: The annihilator method is what suggests $an2^n+b$. The rest is just some computation.

Comment: You can find the solution using the annihilator method in the chat